# nmap without root privileges on exec() php

Tags: php, nmap

I'm trying to do this in PHP:

```
exec("nmap -O x.x.x.x -oX file.xml");
```

But doesn't work because needs `root` privileges (other options that don't require `root` privileges work), is there any way to do this without root privileges?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the file permissions of nmap for php user or execute it as sudo and add the php user to the sudoers for nmap

try visudo and edit the /etc/sudoers
add your php user for local and allow him to run nmap

Comment: This is very dangerous. Making Nmap setuid or allowing restricted users (e.g. "the php user") to run it with root privileges will lead to privilege escalation: anyone can easily use it to launch a root shell.

Comment: So it is not recommended, isn't it?

Comment: ok, finaly I added to `/etc/sudoers` file, this line:
`www-data x.x.x.x = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nmap`
and execute `nmap` with `sudo`

Is it dangerous now?

Comment: if your xxx is protected its ok but not optimal. disable ssh login for xxx aand use it as service account then its ok. depends what you want to do if you just want to run nmap a bash script maybe would do a better job